Kafka - Http Sink Connector not starting up
I am using Confluent Kafka 7.7.1 on local machine and trying to start HTTP Sink Connector in Kafka but continuously getting following validation error:
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,674] INFO REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:320)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,675] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,698] DEBUG Could not parse connector configuration file 'custom/my-http-sink-connector.properties' into a Map with String keys and values (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:131)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,699] DEBUG Could not parse connector configuration file 'custom/my-http-sink-connector.properties' into an object of type CreateConnectorRequest (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:148)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,705] DEBUG Getting plugin class loader: 'PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/Users/deepak.parasnath/Projects/kafka/confluent/confluent-7.7.1/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-http-1.7.7/lib/kafka-connect-http-1.7.7.jar}' for connector: io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:97)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,715] ERROR Failed to create connector for custom/my-http-sink-connector.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:85)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,716] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:96)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/utils/validators/Validators
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.processExtraArgs(ConnectStandalone.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:182)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/utils/validators/Validators
    at io.confluent.connect.http.config.HttpSinkConfig.<clinit>(HttpSinkConfig.java:643)
    at io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector.config(HttpSinkConnector.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:618)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$7(AbstractHerder.java:491)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.utils.validators.Validators
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 9 more
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,717] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,717] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:375)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,717] DEBUG stopping o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@289a3651{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle:212)
[2024-10-28 15:32:13,717] DEBUG Graceful shutdown o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@289a3651{/,null,AVAILABLE} by  (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandlerContainer:167)

My http sink connector properties are as follows:
# The name of the connector
name=my-http-sink-connector

# Connector class for HTTP Sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector

# bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
tasks.max=1

# List of topics that this connector will consume from Kafka
# topics=firstTopic
confluent.topic=firstTopic

# HTTP endpoint to send the data
http.api.url=http://localhost:8080/api/data

# Optional configurations
# HTTP method (POST or PUT)
#http.method=POST
request.method=POST

# Headers to include in the HTTP request (optional)
# http.headers=Content-Type:application/json
header.separator=|
http.headers="Content-Type:application/json|Accept:application/json"

# Maximum number of retries if the request fails
max.retries=3

# Backoff time between retries in milliseconds
retry.backoff.ms=1000

# Number of records to batch before sending an HTTP request
batch.max.size=100

# Additional transformation or converter settings
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

Please help me understand why is breaking here.

How did you install the connector?

I installed it manually, downloaded the connector from https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/http/current/overview.html#install-the-connector-manually and used it

You also need connect-utils on the classpath https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent.kafka/connect-utils

ok, will try and check again
